# Passport-ldapauth - Unauthorized message

Tags: node.js, passport.js

I have been struggling to get this working for a few days now...

I created and entirely stand alone node JS app using express to test this out before I get it into my app...   When I use the hosted test AD from forumsys.com it works perfectly fine.. when hitting my AD, I keep getting the "unauthorized" message.

I cant find a good way to get debug details out of this module... any method I use only returns vague messages...  what does unauthorized mean?  it searched AD but couldnt find the user?  or it couldnt Bind?    I'm thinking it cant bind.

one odd thing, I noticed is that the full DN for my user in my AD has a backslash.

here are my server details: (you can see the commented code from forumsys.com that works great)

```
server: {
  url: 'ldap://ad-prod01.myco.net:389',
  bindDN: 'CN=myapp\, adserver01 (SA),OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users and Groups,DC=myco,DC=net',
  bindCredentials: 'password12345',
  searchBase: 'DC=myco,DC=net',
  searchFilter: '(samaccountname={{username}})'
}
```

here is my full page:

```
    var express      = require('express'),
    passport     = require('passport'),
    bodyParser   = require('body-parser'),
    LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');
    path         = require('path')

var OPTS = {
  server: {
      url: 'ldap://ad-prod01.myco.net:389',
      bindDN: 'CN=myapp\, adserver01 (SA),OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users and Groups,DC=myco,DC=net',
      bindCredentials: 'password12345',
      searchBase: 'DC=myco,DC=net',
      searchFilter: '(samaccountname={{username}})'
    }
  // server: {
  //   url: 'ldap://ldap.forumsys.com',
  //   bindDN: 'cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com',
  //   bindCredentials: 'password',
  //   searchBase: 'dc=example,dc=com',
  //   searchFilter: '(uid={{username}})'
  // }
};

var app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

passport.use(new LdapStrategy(OPTS));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.post('/auth', passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {session: false}), function(req, res) {
  res.send({status: 'ok'});
});

app.get('/login', function(req, res){
  res.render('login', {
    title: 'Portal - Login'
  });

});

app.listen(8443);
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes posting the problem makes the brain click...
 change:

```
bindDN: 'CN=myapp\, adserver01 (SA),OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users and Groups,DC=myco,DC=net',
```

to:

```
bindDN: 'CN=myapp\\, adserver01 (SA),OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users and Groups,DC=myco,DC=net',
```

You need to comment the backslash with another backslash.... SMH!